# JSESSIONID path in firefox and safari is different

Tags: java, tomcat, jsessionid

I am facing a problem with setting the JSESSIONID path.

In firefox it is set to / which is alright but in safari and IE it is somehow set to %22%22 so  i am unable to login using safari and firefox.

I am using tomcat 7 and spring security in backend.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this is due to a bug in tomcat 7.0.1 ...... use tomcat 7.0.2 :)